# How to attach screenshot to the step where it failed?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, hook, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am working on extent report and I want to attach screenshot to the step where it fails and not to the last step. I was using the following code with @After hook, but then it attaches the screenshot to the last step and not the step which failed. I tried changing @After hook to the @AfterStep hook but then the code under that hook doesn't even gets executed.

This hook is defined in package configuration and I have included that package in the glue as specified below:

```
glue = {"stepDefinitions", "configuration"}
```

Code for attaching snapshot:

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;

@After()
     public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) {
          WebDriver driver1 = BaseConfig.setDriver();
          System.out.println("after step");
         if (scenario.isFailed()) {
             System.out.println("scenario failed");
         String screenshotName = scenario.getName().replaceAll(" ", "_");
         System.out.println(screenshotName);
         try {

             File sourcePath = ((TakesScreenshot) driver1).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
             System.out.println(sourcePath);
             File destinationPath = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/cucumber-reports/" + screenshotName + ".png");
             System.out.println(destinationPath);

             Files.copy(sourcePath, destinationPath);   
             destinationPath = new File("./" + screenshotName + ".png");

             Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString());


         } catch (IOException e) {
         } 
         }
         }
```

Depdendencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the version of cucumber & extent reports you are using?

Comment: Updated the problem statement

Comment: if you have recently upgraded to C4, then i would suggest to use cucumber extent report adapter - see doc here - https://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/cucumber4.html

Comment: I did take a look at it after your email but I am not sure if that would help me with reading code from cucumber hook. My concern over here is not being able to invoke code within afterStep hook.

Comment: Also, have you tried suing base64img at your end for any of the project?

Comment: AfterStep can not work at global hooks level. The global hooks can take only scenario as parameter. This means that the screen shot will be attached to scenario, not to the actual step. If you need to attach to step level, then you will have to create a reporter class which extends this adapter and use the annotation @AfterStep on a method to capture & attach screenshot. I have successfully done this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199966/discussion-between-vsingh-and-sureshmani).